# An application is working on one server but doesn't work on another?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a new web application. I've setup the application and it's working on one server(xxx) but it's not working on another(yyy). I changed the web.config file(checked throughly and I've changed the connection string and appsettings).

What could be the error?

The login page is working but when I proceed a Javascript error occurs...

**(Line: 48 Error: Object doesn't support this property or method)**

Here's the code

```
function callCompForFileUpload(responseText)
        {
            document.getElementById("btnView").disabled = false;
            var objFolderUpload = document.getElementById("FolderUpload");
            var UploadURL = document.getElementById("HdnFolderUploadURL").value + "?rid=" + responseText;

        // this is error line
            objFolderUpload.ShowForm(UploadURL);
        }
```

Thanks saj

Comment: what browser are you using? Try some javascript debugger (in Firefox, I'd recommend Firebug). Also make sure that all files are transferred properly (from what you say above, a javascript file might be missing).

Comment: i'm using IE.8.. i'll check and come

Comment: I'd assume that either HdnFolderUploadURL or FolderUpload don't exist and are therefore null.

Comment: @Marko, you can see from the error message that these objects do exist.  It says that the object doesn't support a property or method.  If the object were null, you'd get a message indicating as much.  So, we know that objFolderUpload is a valid element, but that it hasn't been extended to include a `ShowForm` method.  I suspect the method is defined in a linked script that isn't found.

Comment: It doesn't work at firebox also.. now i'm looking is any js missed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing a linked script.  `ShowForm` is not a built-in method on an Element, but it may be defined in a linked script that wasn't copied to your new server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that IIS worker process has write access to the folder that your user uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding the linked script theory. Get a http debugger like the one embedded in firebug or [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to peek into what is happening on the wire. 404 errors will be quite obvious.